# Equation of partial derivatives

Tags: equations, overleaf

How could I write down this equation in latex. As a editor I am using overleaf.

[image]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I would recommend some sort of LaTeX tutorial to help you get started.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally I use for a better alignment of a function assignment `\mathrel{\mathop:}`. Tou can see "The Comprehensive LATEX Symbol List of Scott Pakin (19 January 2017)" at page 49.

[image]

Here my MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}

\[g'(u_t, x_{t-1})\mathrel{\mathop:}=\frac{\partial g(u_t, x_{t-1})}{\partial x_{t-1}}\]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can do that with plain LaTeX, or use a package for a simpler typing:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{diffcoeff}

\begin{document}

\[ g'(u_t, x_{t-1}) = \frac{\partial g(u_t, x_{t-1}) }{\partial x_{t-1}} \]%

\[ g'(u_t, x_{t-1}) = \diffp{g(u_t, x_{t-1})}{x_{t-1}} \]%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
    g'(u_t, x_{t-1}) \coloneqq \frac{\partial g(u_t, u_{t-1})}{\partial x_{t-1}}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want more space between the "equal" sign and the left and right-hand side than just add a `\quad` command before and after it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
    
\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
    g'(u_t, x_{t-1})\quad \coloneqq \quad \frac{\partial g(u_t, u_{t-1})}{\partial x_{t-1}}
\end{equation*}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to set an arbitrary distance between the LHS and the RHS from the "equal" sign you can replace `\quad` with the `\hspace{}` command and adjust the values manually.

Comment: \coloneqq not working.

Comment: sorry, add the mathtools package

Comment: @Encipher I've edited the answer, now it should work

Comment: Please, remove those wrong `\quad` spaces.

Comment: @egreg You surely know a lot more than I do, but I don't understand why they are wrong. The image posted in the question has the LHS and the RHS a bit more separated from the "equal" sign than normal, so I thought that adding `\quad` was a method to increase the spacing.